# Creating a Pivot Table for class grades§

Tags: excel, excel-formula, pivot, pivot-table

I want to create a pivot table for a data set iv been given for my class' final grade outcomes. The data set includes all of their weighted grades for each assessment each student has completed and looks like the example below:

[image]

As you can see each student_id has multiple modules which have multiple weighted assessments. I am unsure how I can calculate outcomes for each module and then their final aggregate grades and place them into some sort of summary table. I have been told that pivot tables are the way to go for this but I don't know where to start.

So I guess my question is how can I collate the data in the examplar into a summary table with final grade outcomes per student?